# Size Up/Down Maco for Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Since Google Sheets does not have a font size up/down keyboard shortcut I decided to try and make my own.  I used the Macro feature and created two separate macros, then opened the script but it didn't work.

I've had a look through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Here's where I am with my code:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Sizeup() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var size = getFontSize();//getFontSize is not standalone
   spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontSize(size+1);//getActiveRangeList() returns an array of Ranges not a Range so no setFontSize() method there
};

function Sizedown() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var size = getFontSize();
   spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontSize(size-1);
};
```

Comment: getActiveRangeList does not return a Range it returns a list of ranges.

Comment: and getFontSize is a method of Range not a standalone function.

Comment: Do you use content assist when your writing code.  If there's not content assist available then most likely you're doing something wrong unless it's a brand new function that's not documented yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function Sizeup() {
   const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const rA=ss.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
   rA.forEach(function(rg,i){
     rg.setFontSize(rg.getFontSize()+1);   
   });
};

function Sizeup() {
   const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const rA=ss.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
   rA.forEach(function(rg,i){
     let s=rg.getFontSize()-1;
     rg.setFontSize((s>0)?s:s+1);   
   });
}
```

Comment: that looked promising...
But, I ran it and got this error
"ReferenceError: getFontSize is not defined"

Comment: Try it again. I had one minor problem but didn't get same error as you did.  And it runs okay.

Comment: Oh I see the problem in your code.  getActiveRangeList does not return a Range it returns an array of Ranges.  So in your case that's right  getActiveRangeList does not have the method set or get FontSize();